# plain and simple

Tags: meaning

"The chimpanzees were jealous, sexist, and possessive, plain and simple."

In the sentence above, are *plain* and *simple* two adjectives describing the chimpanzees or are they part of an idiom emphasizing that the chimpanzees are jealous, sexist and possessive, which is completely true and cannot be described as anything else as in this sentence below:

"It was cheating, plain and simple."

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the context suggests otherwise, it is the latter, as *plain and simple* is a common idiom; most English speakers would recognize it and try to reword the phrase if meant literally.

Comment: the OP's question was not, *is it an idiom*, but *to what does it refer*? I agree this is an idiom, but answers are supposed to address the OP's actual question, or they will be deemed "not an answer".

Answer (score 1):

It means that the conclusion reached by the rest of the sentence is true, "plain and simple"

Comment: You know that this is the case because it is not part of the list: "...jealous, sexist, possessive, plain, and simple." Also because using such a common phrase as part of a list would be insanely confusing.

Answer (score 0):

"Plain and simple" is an idiom, and is used correctly so. "They were X, Y and Z, plain and simple." It is commonly accepted that idioms can stand on their own.